# Work out average in dynamic column window

Tags: excel, dynamic, window

I'm looking for a formula that can work out the average of a row from the furthest right, -30. Hopefully this illustration explains better:

[image]

The red line represents a set amount of columns (30) that stay far-right and then work out the average of numbers within that window. Each day a new column is added and the window needs to continue staying far-right.

Is this possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDEX(1:1,1,MATCH(10^50,1:1,TRUE)),0,-(MIN(30,COLUMN(INDEX(1:1,1,MATCH(10^50,1:1,TRUE))))-1),1,MIN(30,COLUMN(INDEX(1:1,1,MATCH(10^50,1:1,TRUE))))))
```

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET(...))` Taking the average of a range returned by OFFSET.

`INDEX(1:1,1,MATCH(10^50,1:1,TRUE))` The start of the offset - it's the last cell with a value in row 1. MATCHing an unreasonably large number achieves this.

`MIN(30,COLUMN(INDEX(1:1,1,MATCH(10^50,1:1,TRUE)))` Go back the lesser of 30 columns or column A.